# blinking a display using trigger

Tags: fpga, vhdl, display

I've been banging my head over this for a while now, basically I have this display driver that in normal conditions would update a seven segment display continuously.
What I would like to do, and I'm trying to do is create a condition in the module that would send it into a blinking state.

To do this I am using the states of a state machine from my main datapath to store information about the blink, and I'm using a signal "blink" to trigger when to start the blinking sequence.

In my main datapath whenever I want the display to blink, I assign the signal "blink<=not(blink)" essentially, and then my display driver is supposed to notice this change and start the sequence.

The problem is its not noticing the change, or not going into the sequence at all.

Below is my code for the display driver

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Title       : ssd_driver
    -- Design      : lab3_demo
    -- Function:   : generates signals driving four seven segment displays of the Digilent Basys2 or the Digilent Nexys3 board
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.FSM_ATM_pkg.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;

entity ssd_driver is
    generic (   k : integer := 20 );
        --  k depends on the on the clock frequency selected on the board
        --  k := 20 for fclk = 100 MHz
        --  k := 19 for fclk = 50 MHz
        --  k := 18 for fclk = 25 MHz
    port(
        clk     : in    std_logic;
        rst     : in    std_logic; 
        hex0    : in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        hex1    : in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        hex2    : in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        hex3    : in    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        seg     : out   std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        an      : out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        STATE : in mycases1;
        blink : in std_logic);
end entity;

architecture arch of ssd_driver is

    -- intermediate signals and constants
    signal decoder_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal q : std_logic_vector(k-1 downto 0);
    signal mux_out : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sel : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 

    signal timer: unsigned(31 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    signal delay: unsigned(3 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    signal blinktimer: unsigned(31 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    signal cont_decoder_out: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal blink_flip:std_logic;
    signal hex_out:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal sequence:std_logic:='0';
    signal hex0tmp,hex1tmp,hex2tmp,hex3tmp:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal pastblink:std_logic:='0';
    signal blink_detect: std_logic;

    constant HIGH : std_logic := '1';
    constant LOW : std_logic := '0';
    constant ONESECOND: integer:=100000000;
    constant blink_rate:integer:=ONESECOND/2;


begin   




    process(clk)
        begin
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    if pastblink /= blink then
                        sequence<='1';
                    end if;
                    if timer>delay*ONESECOND then
                            sequence<='0';
                            pastblink<=blink;
                    end if;
                    if sequence = '1' then  

                        timer<=timer+1;
                        blinktimer<=blinktimer+1;

                        case STATE is 
                            when PIN=> delay<=to_unsigned(3,4);
                            when BAL=> delay<=to_unsigned(0,4);
                            when COUT=> delay<=to_unsigned(5,4);
                            when CIN=>  delay<=to_unsigned(5,4);
                            when CHEC=> delay<=to_unsigned(5,4);
                            when CPIN=> delay<=to_unsigned(3,4);
                            when others=> delay<=to_unsigned(0,4);
                        end case;

                        if blinktimer= to_unsigned(blink_rate,32) then
                            blinktimer<=(others=>'0');
                            blink_flip<=not(blink_flip);
                            case blink_flip is
                                when '1' => cont_decoder_out<="1111";
                                when '0' => cont_decoder_out<=decoder_out;
                                when others => cont_decoder_out<=decoder_out;
                            end case;
                        end if;

                    else 
                        blink_flip<='0';
                        timer<=(others=>'0');
                        blinktimer<=(others=>'0');      
                    end if;
                end if;


    end process;

    hex0tmp<=hex_out(7 downto 0) when sequence ='1' else hex0;
    hex1tmp<=hex_out(15 downto 8) when sequence ='1' else hex1;
    hex2tmp<=hex_out(23 downto 16) when sequence ='1' else hex2;
    hex3tmp<=hex_out(31 downto 24) when sequence ='1' else hex3;

    an <= cont_decoder_out when sequence = '1' else not decoder_out;

    up_counter2 : entity work.up_counter generic map ( k => k ) port map ( clk => clk, rst => rst, init => LOW, enable => HIGH, count => q);

    sel <= q(k-1 downto k-2);


    with sel select  
        mux_out <=  hex0tmp when "00",
                        hex1tmp when "01",
                        hex2tmp when "10",
                        hex3tmp when others;

    with sel select  
        decoder_out <=  "0001" when "00",
                                "0010" when "01",
                                "0100" when "10",
                                "1000" when others;


    -- hex-to-7-segment decoding
    with mux_out select
        seg(6 downto 0) <=  "1000000" when x"00", -- 0  
                            "1111001" when x"01", -- 1  or i
                            "0100100" when x"02", -- 2  
                            "0110000" when x"03", -- 3  
                            "0011001" when x"04", -- 4  
                            "0010010" when x"05", -- 5  
                            "0000010" when x"06", -- 6  
                            "1111000" when x"07", -- 7  
                            "0000000" when x"08", -- 8  
                            "0010000" when x"09", -- 9  
                            "0001000" when x"0a", -- a  
                            "0000011" when x"0b", -- b  
                            "1000110" when x"0c", -- c  
                            "0100001" when x"0d", -- d  
                            "0000110" when x"0e", -- e  
                            "0001110" when x"0f", -- f  
                            "0001100" when x"11", -- p
                            "1001000" when x"12", -- n
                            "1000001" when x"13", --u
                            "0001001" when x"14", -- h
                            "1111111" when others;

end arch;
```

Are there any obvious reasons why it shouldn't be working?  The blink<=not(blink) statement is inside a clocked process in the main datapath by the way.

Also if anyone knows a better way to implement this thats always helpful, although I would really like to know how to get my idea of noticing the change of blink to trigger the sequence to work.

Thanks in advance as always!

Answer (score 1):

Your coding style needs a lot of work. The main problem is that you never use your hardware reset signal `rst` to initialize anything other than `up_counter2`. This means that all of your state variables can start up holding random values.

Your trigger code can be separated out into its own process, like this:

```
  process (clk) begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if pastblink /= blink then
        sequence <= '1';
      end if;

      if timer > delay*ONESECOND then
        sequence <= '0';
        pastblink <= blink;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
```

There are two different assignments to `sequence`. In a process, it will be the *final* assignment that applies. Suppose your systems starts up in a state in which `sequence` is false, but the expression `timer > delay*ONESECOND` is true. This means that regardless of what happens with `blink` and `pastblink`, `sequence` can never be set to true. Furthermore, since `sequence` is false, neither `timer` nor `delay` will ever be updated.

There are several other problems in your code. These include:

- No assignment to `hex_out`.
- The `an` signal is sometimes the complement of `decoder_out` and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: q is the output of up_counter2. While he's at it, a ROM could be used to avoid multiplying delay*ONESECOND.  And why aren't timer and blink timer sensitive to the fclk rate (or derived from a q value as an enable)?

Comment: @DavidKoontz: Ah, thanks, I missed that connection. But why did he use an `up_counter` for that, but not for `timer` or `blinktimer`?